# php substr start position not working

Tags: php, string

I have a problem here with the php function [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Let's say I have this string coming from an xml file:

```
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><bookstore id="book-1"><languages default="en">';
```

What I'm trying to do is I'm trying to extract the second tag from that string, the tag

```
<bookstore id="book-1">
```

So what I did was this:

First, I got the string starting with the second tag like so:

```
$newStr = substr($str, strpos($str, '<bookstore '));
```

My variable **$newStr** should now be:

```
$newStr = '<bookstore id="book-1"><languages default="en">';
```

Then, using that **$newStr** variable, I tried to get the tag that I wanted (the second tag, which is now the first tag of my **$newStr** variable) like this:

```
$wantedTag = substr($newStr, 0, strpos($newStr, '>');
```

But the problem I'm having is that Nothing is returned (or maybe empty string is returned) when I do this. But if I replace the 0 by 1 like so:

```
$wantedTag = substr($newStr, 1, strpos($newStr, '>');
```

I get my second tag but without the initial '<':

```
$wantedTag = 'bookstore id="book-1">';
```

Which makes total sense because the character 'b' is at position 1. Why am I not getting anything (or empty string) when I put the start position of the substr function to 0? Any help will be very appreciated.

Please don't tell me to use any of those XML parsers out there like SimpleXML and stuff, this has nothing to do with XML Parsing, it's just basic string manipulation techniques.

Comment: Whilst it may be string manipulation, your example is a bad candidate. This would be far better solved with an XML parser, of which PHP has a few.

Comment: `...it's just basic string manipulation techniques.`  I would call it not using the right tool for the job.

Comment: Use an XML parser for crying out loud!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `substr($newStr, 0, strpos($newStr, '>'))` returns the tag, starting with < and up to (but not including) >.

Comment: I know this would be better solve with an XML parser, but nobody can tell me why am I getting empty string? Why I can't get the '<' to be printed out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you're looking at the result *in your browser*? The browser will of course *interpret* any HTML/XML tags, so unless the tag has some content, you won't see anything of it. The string processing itself seems to work fine, see http://codepad.org/xkU86CJP.

Comment: Ok, I see that when you add +1 in $wantedTag = substr($newStr, 0, strpos($newStr, '>') + 1); it works. But I don't really see what difference does that +1 make (without the +1 it does not work

Comment: Ok I get it, the +1 actually makes it take the closing braket in $wanted tag. Without it, the closing bracket will be missing in the string. Also, I noticed that in Firefox the code behaves correctly, whereas in Chrome it does not do anything. That's strange